# tSQL to set up user with View Definition permission on SQL Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to export a SQL Azure database to a `.bacpac` file using the Azure portal. The administrator **username** on my database contains a `*`. When I use it in the username field I get this error.

```
The login name must meet the following requirements:
It must be a SQL Identifier.
It cannot be a system name, for example:
- admin, administrator, sa, root, dbmanager, loginmanager, etc.
- Built-in database user or role like dbo, guest, public, etc. 
It cannot contain:
 - White space like spaces, tabs, or returns
 - Unicode characters
 - Nonalphabetic characters ("|:*?\/#&;,%=)
It cannot begin with:
 - Digits (0 through 9)
 - @, $, +
```

So I add a new user to the database using the following tSQL.

```
USE master;
CREATE LOGIN gu6t6rdb WITH PASSWORD = 'kjucuejcj753jc8j'

USE MyActualDB;
CREATE USER gu6t6rdb FOR LOGIN gu6t6rdb
```

The portal export form accepts that username but later errors with the following message.

> Error encountered during the service operation. Could not extract
>   package from specified database. The reverse engineering operation
>   cannot continue because you do not have View Definition permission on
>   the 'MyActualDB' database.

To fix this I tried the following tSQL

```
GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO gu6t6rdb
```

which throws the following error

> Securable class 'server' not supported in this version of SQL Server

How should I use tSQL to provide an additional user on my database and give the user sufficient privileges to export the database through the Azure portal to a `.bacpac` file in an Azure blobstore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it. I can add the user to the `db_owner` role and then the export proceeds without error.

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'gu6t6rdb'
```

Comment: this is not the best idea to give DBO rights for essentially read-only users (if you need to export only).

Comment: You definitively *don't* want to do that. Unless you really don't care about the database.

Answer (score 26):

This will not work on sql azure. You will need to grant view definition at the database level. (without the ANY keyword)

GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO gu6t6rdb

P.S: I hit the exact same issue and this seemed to solve my problem. I also had to do a Grant Execute (but it depends on what your bacpac is applying to the database)

Answer (score 4):

as of now, `GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO [username]` works in Azure SQL, I just verified it myself. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15 for reference:
[image]

So in order to successfully export database as bacpak file you can created contained user (no need in `CREATE LOGIN...` command) and give the following permissions:

```
CREATE USER [user_from_azure_AD] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [user_from_azure_AD] 
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO [user_from_azure_AD]
```