# Server level Admin Rights not working?

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms

I created a `server` on `Microsoft Azure`, and a `SQL database` on it. I downloaded `SQL Server Management Studio`, and I am able to connect to the server fine using the Server `Admin` Id and password I created when creating the `server`. But when I try and run a `bulk load query` to insert a picture in a picture column. It says I do not have rights. Error is:

> You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement

Also in `Management studio` if I go to server level `security` folder I have logins as an option and the Server Admin ID is there, when I right click to go to properties, its missing properties as an option.

Let me know if you need more info.

Any help is appreciated,

Thank you,

Abdul

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604416/how-to-enable-bulk-permission-in-sql-server) solution. You have to add bulkadmin rights.

Comment: I tried that first before posting, it gives an error saying "Securable class 'server' not supported in this version of SQL Server." also I have nothing under security other than the logins folder no roles or anything. No BulkAdmin role. Using SSMS 2016.

Comment: A SQL Server and database on Azure is not the same as an on premise server/database. You could create a VM and install a SQL Server on the VM. Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036156/tsql-to-set-up-user-with-view-definition-permission-on-sql-azure) can solve you not supported problem.